# Evaluate the result of a Zero-sum game

Tags: visualization, game

I'm currently working on an AI playing Mandarin using Minimax. I can extract this dictionary from a game where 2 AI with different depth plays with each other:

```py
game_result = {
    "winner": winner,         # 1, 2 for player 1 and 2 respectively
    "time": time,             # time[1] for player 1's total time consumed, same with time[2]
    "score": score,           # same as time
    "total_turn": total_turn  # same as time
}
```

I'll run about 100 games.
Can anyone help me with how I can analyze this data? I'm thinking of the win rate of each depth (like bot1: depth=1, bot2: depth 2, and bot2 win 70% of 100 games), but I want to also make use of the time, score, and turn.

I'm new to this field, therefore anything will help.